# Is the usage of "smiled in silent congratulation" correct in this context?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

I came across the below line from [The Righteous Life: The Very Best of A.P.J. Abdul Kalam](https://www.amazon.in/Righteous-Life-P-J-Abdul-Kalam/dp/812913456X) book I'm currently reading. While I could comprehend the meaning in this context, wondering the usage of "... smiled in silent congratulation for the award" in the sentence. I was wondering if some connecting word is missing here in printing, or if this could have been written more clearly as "... smiled in silent *congratulating* me for the award".

> The mess bearer brought me my breakfast of idlis and buttermilk and
> smiled in silent congratulation for the award.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine, especially in formal writing, to use 'in' after a verb of bodily action and before a noun of attitude, behaviour, emotion, etc (and 'congratulation' is such a noun).

*She frowned in frustration.

I shivered in fear.

John blinked in surprise.*